# Explain brute force algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a brute force algorithm, but never fully understood it.  I have a vague grasp of some of the things that go on, but every time I try to follow what happens exactly, I get lost (for example, the `index` variable is a little confusing).  Any offers on how to make the algorithm more efficient are also welcome.

**Note** - I already have the algorithm, and it compiles and works.  Please don't accuse me of trying to use this for malicious intent, because I haven't used it for that purpose, and I never plan to.  I just want to know how it works.

```
public class BruteForceTest
{
    public String username = new String();
    public static String password = "ZZZZZ";
    public static char[] charset = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray();
    private static char[] currentGuess = new char[1];

public static void bruteForce()
    {
        String attempt = new String();
        Date start = new Date();
        while (true)
        {
            if (attempt.equals(password))
            {
                Date end = new Date();
                System.out.println("Password: " + attempt + "\nTotal time to crack: " + ((end.getTime() - start.getTime()) / 1000) + " seconds." + "\n");
                break;
            }
            attempt = in.toString();
            // System.out.println("Tried: " + attempt);
            in.increment();
        }
    }

    public BruteForceTest()
    {
        Arrays.fill(currentGuess, charset[0]);
    }

    public void increment()
    {
        int index = currentGuess.length - 1;
        while (index >= 0)
        {
            if (currentGuess[index] == charset[charset.length - 1])
            {
                if (index == 0)
                {
                    currentGuess = new char[currentGuess.length + 1];
                    Arrays.fill(currentGuess, charset[0]);
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    currentGuess[index] = charset[0];
                    index--;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                currentGuess[index] = charset[Arrays.binarySearch(charset, currentGuess[index]) + 1];
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return String.valueOf(currentGuess);
    }
}
```

Comment: Brute Force is not a name of a concrete algorithm. you should state what are you using this algorithm for.

Comment: @Headshota actually, it is. Brute Force is the algorithm that enumerates all valid passwords and tries them one by one.

Comment: This is a simple bit of Java code.  If you don't understand it, I recommend that you start by buying a good Java programming text book.  If you have a specific question, maybe we can answer that.  But "please explain this" is not constructive ...

Comment: @Anony-Mousse - actually "brute force" is a name for *any* algorithm that involves trying all possible candidate solutions in an unintelligent way.  For example, one could (in theory) use "brute force" to solve a Soduku ...

Comment: Of course. But it would still be "brute force". The name *is* comparably as descriptive as "Dijkstra search". You can also solve very different problems with Dijkstra style search.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse - nope. Dijkstra search is a specific algorithm for a specific class of problems.  Brute force is so generic that it applies to any problem in which you can iterate over the possible solutions.  (It doesn't even need to be a finite set of solutions ...)

Comment: @StephenC "Proof" by Professor Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_search#Basic_algorithm  and I bet you will find various lecture slides that discuss a similar "basic brute force algorithm". And while Dijkstra *originally* is a shortest path in graphs algorithm, it *can* be used in very different domains, such as finding the differences between two XML documents (look it up).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Brute forcing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_search) is a heuristic technique that means, essentially, you're going to try to analyze every possible scenario by taking advantage of how much faster a computer is than a human brain.  For example, you're not trying to deductively figure out the password or the next best move in a Chess game; you just test every possible situation and use the right one (or the best one according to some metric, depending on what the brute force algorithm is meant to accomplish).

Your code simply goes through all the possible values that could be held for a password and checks to see whether it has found it or not.  If it doesn't, it moves on to the next possible combination until it does.

It's also a demonstration of a [worst-case scenario](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best,_worst_and_average_case#Worst-case_versus_average-case_performance), since the password, being defined as `ZZZZZ`, will be the last thing the algorithm attempts as a solution (assuming the maximum password length is defined as five characters.)

Also, as far as you being worried that people think you're using this algorithm for malicious purposes, I wouldn't be too concerned.  Hardly any computer systems would actually be vulnerable to this kind of attack, and you would be locked out long before you ever actually happened upon a password.