# How to get every possibility of a string with at least one of a certain letter removed

Tags: java, string, combinations

I'm a bit novice at Java, so this may be common sense to somebody else...

I am trying to write a method that takes an input string of any length and returns a list of every possible variation of the string with at least one "i" removed.

For example, the input could be "kikikifiki". The output will be a list containing the word with 0 "i"s removed ("kikikifiki"), each word with one "I" removed ("kikikifik", "kikikifki", etc.), each word with two "I"s removed ("kikikifk", "kikikfik", etc.), and so on. The output may have any amount of "i"s.

So far, I came up with something a little like this:

```
String word = /*input goes here; has only a-zA-Z*/;
String hypo[] = new String[10000];
String wordOriginal = word;
String temp = word;
for (int g=0;g<(wordOriginal.replaceAll("[^i]","")).length();g++) {
    while (word.contains("i")) {
        for(int j=0; j<numI; j++) {
            //Test the current prefix with each following 'i' removed.
            temp = word.substring(0,temp.indexOf("i")+j) + temp.substring(word.indexOf("i")+j+1);
            hypo[index] = prefix + temp;
            for (int h=j; h>0; h--)
                temp = temp.substring(0,temp.indexOf("i")) + temp.substring(temp.indexOf("i")+1);
            index++;
        }
        word = word.substring(0,word.indexOf("i")) + word.substring(word.indexOf("i")+1);
        temp = word;
        numI = (word.replaceAll("[^i]","")).length();
    }
    word = wordOriginal;
    for (int ghj=0;ghj<g;ghj++)
        prefix = word.substring(0,word.indexOf("i")+1);
    word = word.substring(word.indexOf("i")+1);
    temp = word;
    numI = (word.replaceAll("[^i]","")).length();
}
```

It doesn't quite work, though. I know that I should probably use a list of hypo instead of an array, but I feel like there is more I can do to make this elegant and, well, operative.

Any ideas?

-

EDIT: Somebody suggested that I put the desired output with the actual output. I also added the code below to match my entire code as of yet.

INPUT:

> rifi

DESIRED OUTPUT: (not necessarily in this order)

> rf
>   rif
>   rfi
>   rifi

ACTUAL OUTPUT:

> rf
>   rfi
>   rif
>   rf
>   f

-

INPUT:

> kiraiki

DESIRED OUTPUT: (not necessarily in this order)

> krak
>   kirak
>   kraik
>   kraki
>   kiraik
>   kiraki
>   kraiki
>   kiraiki

ACTUAL OUTPUT:

> krak
>   kraiki
>   kiraiki
>   kiraiki
>   kraki
>   kraik
>   krak
>   raki
>   raik
>   rak
>   kiraki
>   kiraik
>   kirak

-

Entire code:

```
package com;

/*public class KidishToEnglish {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //BruteForce brute = new BruteForce();
        //brute.bruteForce();
    }
}
*/

import java.util.Scanner;

public class KidishToEnglish
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(true)
        {
            String word = "";

            //Get the word.
            System.out.print("Input:\n>> ");
            while (word.equals(""))
            {
                word = fixword(keyboard.nextLine().toLowerCase());
                if (word.equals("") || word.contains(" "))
                {
                    System.out.print("\nPlease input one single word.\n>> ");
                    word = "";
                }
                if (!legal(word))
                {
                    System.out.print("\nThis word contains illegal letters.\n>> ");
                    word = "";
                }
            }

            //Remove unnecessary letters.
            if (word.substring(word.length()-1).equals("u"))
                word = word.substring(0, word.length()-1);
            if (word.substring(word.length()-2).equals("es"))
                word = word.substring(0, word.length()-2);
            if (word.substring(word.length()-2).equals("in"))
                word = word.substring(0, word.length()-2);

            //Set up hypotheticals. For example, "rifi" would become an array containing "rf", "rfi", "rif", and "rifi".
            int numI = (word.replaceAll("[^i]","")).length();
            int index = 0;
            String wordOriginal = word;
            String prefix = "";
            String hypo[] = new String[10000];
            hypo[index] = word.replace("i","");
            index++;

            String temp = word;
            for (int g=0;g<(wordOriginal.replaceAll("[^i]","")).length();g++)
            {
                while (word.contains("i"))
                {
                    for(int j=0; j<numI; j++)
                    {
                        //Test the current prefix with each following 'i' removed.
                        temp = word.substring(0,temp.indexOf("i")+j) + temp.substring(word.indexOf("i")+j+1);
                        hypo[index] = prefix + temp;
                        for (int h=j; h>0; h--)
                            temp = temp.substring(0,temp.indexOf("i")) + temp.substring(temp.indexOf("i")+1);
                        index++;
                    }
                    word = word.substring(0,word.indexOf("i")) + word.substring(word.indexOf("i")+1);
                    temp = word;
                    numI = (word.replaceAll("[^i]","")).length();
                }
                word = wordOriginal;
                for (int ghj=0;ghj<g;ghj++)
                    prefix = word.substring(0,word.indexOf("i")+1);
                word = word.substring(word.indexOf("i")+1);
                temp = word;
                numI = (word.replaceAll("[^i]","")).length();
            }



            boolean test = true;
            int testnum = 0;
            while (test)
            {
                if(testnum >= index)
                    test = false;
                else
                    System.out.println(hypo[testnum]);
                    testnum++;
            }

        }
    }





    public static String fixword(String word)
    {
        word = word.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]","");
        word = word.trim();
        return word;
    }

    public static boolean legal(String word)
    {
        return ((word.replaceAll("[abdefhikmrsuw]","")).equals(""));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that a homework or what? Why would you need to do this IRL?

Comment: I'd use it for generating strings during a bruteforce session if I knew certain characters or character combinations weren't going to be used.

Comment: @MightyPork: This is part of the decoder for something I am working on.

Comment: @MxuL: Oh, I've never heard of bruteforce. I did a quick search...so, it basically checks the input every single combinations of all letters it could possibly have? That /may/ work...the possible input letters are limited. I'll consider that...but I don't think that's very elegant anyway.

Comment: Brute force is not supposed to be elegant, that's why it's called brute..

Comment: When asking questions with "it doesn't show what I want", please remember to include actual output, and the expected output. That makes it much easier to help.

Comment: Your question does not seem consistent. First it says that the string needs to have "at least one 'i' removed", but then in the example you include the word "with 0 'i's removed".

Comment: @RetoKoradi Well, 0 "i"s removed is just the source word. That should be as easy as hypo[0] = word (or better, hypo.add(word)).

Comment: @Patrick, Alright, I will keep that in mind in the future. I'll edit the question now to add that. I did explain the desired output, however...

Comment: @KupferudelWolf: Yes, you did good, but including both expected and actual is better :-)

Comment: @Patrick Done! I also included the entire code at the bottom because, well, it can't hurt. Thank you for your help so far, though...and everyone else, too.

Comment: @MxyL I tried a simple bruteforce program that somebody else created here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14094864/explain-brute-force-algorithm

It takes exceedingly too long, even if I limit it to the 12 letters that the code can use. I expected it to take long...but by long, I was thinking thirty seconds...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very naive implementation, simply removing one character at a time and iterating over the new list of values. This is not very efficient performancewise, since many of the nodes get revisited several times.

Consider for instance when we have two strings `kirk` and `krik` and remove one `i` from both, resulting in the same string. This is mitigated in the solution by using a HashSet, which will filter out any duplicates along the way.

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String word = "kiraiki";
    Set<String> process = new HashSet<String>();
    System.out.println("Initial word: " + word);
    process.add(word);
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; ++i) {
      System.out.println("Removing " + i);
      Set<String> next = new HashSet<String>();
      for (String current : process) {
        List<String> result = removeOne(current, "i");
        for (String r : result) {
          next.add(r);
        }
      }
      for (String r : next) {
        System.out.println(r);
      }
      process = next;
    }
  }

  public static List<String> removeOne(String word, String c) {
    List<String> oneRemoved = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] parts = word.split(c, -1);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < parts.length-1; ++i){
      for (int j = 0; j < parts.length; ++j){
        String part = parts[j];
        builder.append(part);
        if (i != j){
          builder.append('i');
        }
      }
      oneRemoved.add(builder.substring(0, builder.length() - 1).toString());
      builder.setLength(0);
    }
    return oneRemoved;
  }
}
```

Perhaps this can give you some new ideas for a better solution.

Comment: I added `int numI = word.replace("i","").length();` after the initialization of `word` and changed the `for` statement to `for (int i = 1; i <= numI; i++)` to allow the program to support words with more than or fewer than four "i"s. After that, this worked well.

I understand this 100%. I needless-to-say replaced `System.out.println(r);` with `resultList.add(r);` after initiating the ArrayList elsewhere.

It does run somewhat slowly, but it's exponentially faster than just bruteforce. Until I understand the other one 100%, I will certainly use this one. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can almost treat this like going to `0 to N` (where N is the total number of occurrences of the char you are looking for) in **binary**, e.g. `00000 to 11111`. That is *(2^N) - 1 combinations*, so brute force search and replace won't work so nicely.

Well we can use this to our advantage. First let's make an array with all the locations of the char we would like to remove.

```
static List<Integer> location = new ArrayList<Integer>();
static String word = "kiraiki";
static String remove = "i";
int index = word.indexOf(remove);
while (index >= 0) {
    location.add(index);
    index = word.indexOf(remove, index + 1);
}
```

Now we have a `N` i.e. `location.size();` locations of `remove` that we need to replace. Let's go through all the binary combinations from `0 to N` and replace the corresponding char location in `location.get(i)`.

```
public static void binaryReplace(int value){
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.pow(2, value); i++) {

        StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder(Integer.toBinaryString(i));
        // Add Leading '0's
        for(int j = binary.length(); j < value; j++) {
            binary.insert( 0, '0' );
        }

        // Create a temp with the original word. 
        StringBuilder tmp = new StringBuilder(word);
        // Look for where all the '1's (trues) are in the binary number 
        for (int k = -1; (k = binary.indexOf("1", k + 1)) != -1; ) {
            // I'm using spaces here so has to not have indexing issues with '' chars.
            tmp.setCharAt(location.get(k), ' ');
        }
        // Now let's just replace these spaces so we can get the print out we want. 
        System.out.println(tmp.toString().replaceAll("\\s", ""));
    }
}
```

The binaryReplace function can be significantly improved (you can remove a few binary combinations that produce the same result, there's a lot of searching, etc.) but this should get you started.

Comment: *discretely Googles "StringBuilder"*

Well, I would not have thought about using binary to do this, though it makes sense. I'm starting to understand the code, though, which is good...

The code works, but it has the duplicates that you foretold. As a novice Java programmer, the only idea I have is to test each outcome against the other outcomes so far, but I know it will slow the program down that way. This may be something I should return to with a little more knowledge...or when it's not 1:00 AM. I'll see what the other guy suggested...but this works, so thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

How about getting the power set of the letter you want to remove then 'masking' out the results.
i.e. find position of all the i's in the String then generate the power set.

For example, with input “kiki” the power set of the position of the i's would be:
{} {1} {3} {1,3}

so then masking out the results would give.
    {} = kiki
    {1} = k#ki
    {3} = kik#
    {1,3}= k#k#

i.e. kiki kki kik kk

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.lang.Integer;

    public class Stack {    

        private static String input = "kiraiki";    

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            char[] original = input.toCharArray();      
            SortedSet<Integer> iPos = findI(original);
            Set<Set<Integer>> powerOfI = power(iPos);
            getResults(original, powerOfI);     
        }

        private static void getResults(char[] original, Set<Set<Integer>> powerOfI) {
            StringBuilder sb;
            char[] copyOfOriginal;
            for (Set<Integer> combinationOfI : powerOfI) {          
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                copyOfOriginal = Arrays.copyOf(original, original.length);          
                for (int posOfI : combinationOfI) {
                    copyOfOriginal[posOfI] = '#';               
                }           
                for (int i = 0; i < original.length; i++) {

                    if (copyOfOriginal[i] != '#') {
                        sb.append(copyOfOriginal[i]);
                    }               
                }
                System.out.println(sb.toString());          
            }
        }

        private static Set<Set<Integer>> power(SortedSet<Integer> setOfI) {             
            List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(setOfI);
            int n = list.size();    
            Set<Set<Integer>> allTheI = new HashSet<Set<Integer>>();    
            for( long i = 0; i < (1 << n); i++) {
                Set<Integer> itemI = new HashSet<Integer>();
                for( int j = 0; j < n; j++ )
                    if( (i >> j) % 2 == 1 ) itemI.add(list.get(j));
                allTheI.add(itemI);
            }   
            return allTheI;
        }

        private static SortedSet<Integer> findI(char[] original) {
            SortedSet<Integer> iPos = new TreeSet<Integer>();
            for (int i = 0; i < original.length; i++) {
                if (original[i] == 'i') {
                    iPos.add(i);
                }
            }
            return iPos;
        }
    }
```